Is teaching how to solve recurrence relations using generating functions too much for a first year discrete maths course?
I'm teaching discrete mathematics at a local university (some lecturing but mainly tutorials), and as many of you probably know such courses are filled to the brim with content. There's logic, combinatorics, functions and realtions, graph theory, and recurrence relations. (My background is a PhD in Logic, but I've taken this subject on because I really like the themes and topics contained in it.)
It's impossible to cover these topics in depth. Some selected topics may go beyond elementary, but that's it. In the recurrence relations section, aside from some pretty motivation to the topic, as far as solving them I have been only covering the iteration method and also the characterictic polynomial approach to homogenous linear recurrence relations with constant ceofficients, and in practice we don't go beyond third order. Basically not much more beyond what can be found in the Susanna Epp textbook.
I was wondering however, whether it makes sense to try to cover the generating functions approach to solving recurrence relations? I feel that introducing the methodology alone would take a fair amount of time, and solving even simple examples that can be done fairly easily with other methods seems quite complicated. I think that it would be nice to devote more time to this, but not in a first level discrete maths course.
What are your thoughts? I'll appreciate any feedback.

Wait - do your students know anything about differential equations?  Do they even know about Taylor series?  It seems like those topics are crucial to appreciating generating functions.

At the university I graduated from, this material was taught in the second semester of discrete math, which would still be in the first year. But I don't think we completed our study - it was at the very end of the semester and treated a bit like a "stretch goal".

One more data point to add.  I tutor primarily university math, including lots of Discrete Math in particular.  Even after working with 100 or more students on Discrete, it's quite rare, as in maybe 5% or less for 1st semester Discrete students to see generating functions.

A better question to ask- what Discrete Math topics will students need in their future courses and careers?  My understanding is that graph theory is foundational to AI and data science, which are obviously rapidly growing career options.

I feel like there is a lot of assumed risk in doing this. In discrete math, the infinite series are treated entirely formally which can create significant misconceptions about infinite series that then must be corrected for in calculus or analysis courses.

I spent about 20 minutes on this subject. It's not that difficult if you have a deck of slides and quickly go over the step used instead of trying to do them on a white/black board.

I think this is a good question, and I spent a few years teaching discrete math with the mystery, "why are we even teaching recurrence relations?" manifest in my head. N.B., my community college uses Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, and our course is CS-coded (required for both CS and math majors).
Here's what I came up with for a belated answer in my case. The real payoff is for students to know about recurrence relations some time later, when we can present algorithmic functions in a recursive form, and so count the number of operations via a recurrence relation, and so make use of the Master Theorem to look up their big-O complexity value.
Now, in my case, our course syllabus didn't cover this later section on algorithmic complexity, so the whole topic was invisible to me until some later date when I sat down and read the entire book from cover to cover (I have a math degree instead of CS, so it wasn't part of my prior education). But I now feel it's arguably the single most important topic in the book, especially for the CS majors we're targeting. It's also one of the recommended ACM Core Competencies for CS programs in the first two years (C.2.2-AL.C):

Use recurrence relations to determine the time complexity of
recursively defined algorithms by solve [sic] elementary recurrence
relations and present the results to a group of scholars.

As a result, I've been pushing to get this topic of the Master Theorem specifically on our common syllabus and covered by all of our instructors (who like me are mostly math and not CS-trained people). In doing so, we would (a) address the principal result in CS in the course, (b) satisfy the ACM core competency requirement, and (c) give a coherent use-case application for recurrence relations.
So, to address the OP's question: My objective would be to get students to have the most minimal familiarity with recurrence relations we can get away with before seeing the Master Theorem. The specific solution techniques are almost irrelevant IMO. If I can get away with no solving exercises I might do that. If I have to give them a brief introductory exercise set, where they just guess & check solutions, that would suffice to give some time thinking about their existence. (In Rosen, generating functions appear in the section right after the Master Theorem, and aren't used again later.)
In general, I find that the discrete math class (among others) is at great risk of facing a time crunch, slicing off the pinnacle results, and then looking like a pile of unrelated pointless topics. In this light, I would certainly avoid generating functions or any other advanced solution method; far more important is to have time on the schedule for their application in the Master Theorem.

I love logic, and I've taught discrete a number of times (most often using Levin's OER). I have not studied generating functions in any depth. I agree with your characterization of the course as filled to the brim with topics. It sounds like you love the power of generating functions, and want to share your love.
I wonder if you might want to ask a few good students if they'd like to do extra work with you (no credit, no grade) on this topic. That way you wouldn't be taking time away from everything else, and you also wouldn't be trying to squeeze it into just a day or two. But more importantly, you wouldn't be requiring the whole class to think about this very strange topic.
What I know about generating functions comes from a delightful book titled Math Girls, by Hiroshi Yuki. In chapter 4, the characters explore generating functions. It was so strange, I had to work through it multiple times. I looked for textbooks that might explain it better but found none I liked.
It was fascinating, but very weird.

I think that characterising generating functions as a "very strange topic" is just a function of unfamiliarity—which is reasonable enough, but the whole topic, including the idea of proving things that are just obvious, is very strange for students, so I'm not sure that they'd see generating functions as that much stranger unless the teacher encouraged them to do so!

@LSpice, yeah, I hear you. But ... It's strange in a similar way to how LaPlace transforms are strange: convert problem to an entirely different sort of problem, solve that, and then come back home.

@SueVanHattum: "It's strange in a similar way to how LaPlace transforms are strange" Which is due to the fact that the generating function of a sequence is the discrete-time Laplace transform of the sequence. ;-) I think this is actually quite a good argument for teaching generating functions: it is a nice preparation for solving differential equations by Laplace transforms.

@JochenGlueck If so, then we need to rearrange courses somehow.

@SueVanHattum: Hmm, I don't know math curricula in the US very well. Are ordinary differential equations often taught before discrete math?

@JochenGlueck Nope. But discrete is taught mainly in service to CS (at many community (2-year) colleges), and is already packed.

@SueVanHattum: I see. Thanks for your reply!

And most of those CS majors will never see differential equations.  Many of them won’t see two semesters of calculus.

@SueVanHattum, the book by Wilf "generatingfunctionology" (https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) is a clear explanation; Flajolet and Sedgewick "Analytic Combinatorics" (https://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) showcases the immense power of the method (the second is heavy going, though).

You can always try it once and if it goes terribly badly then you'll have a great story to tell as to why you don't teach the very interesting topic. Bonus points if spending time on this topic pushes an uninteresting one off the list of topics for that given term. That said, if it actually is the case that teaching it makes it impossible to reasonable get to the rest of the material, then probably it shouldn't be your habitual practice in the course. The benefit of teaching this topic is that you are excited about the prospect of teaching it and it will likely demonstrate your particular passion for mathematics. Students can be inspired by such practice, it's part of how we find new members of our community.

@Mariusz Popieluch: A possible intermediate approach is to prepare materials for the 2 or 3 students who are most interested and capable of pursuing this, perhaps in exchange for a guaranteed 'A' in the course if they've achieved an A average on all pre-final-exam major tests (essentially, they can skip the final exam in the course). Having to prepare the materials and getting a feel for where student stumbling blocks are might be helpful in later scaling up to the entire class, or in deciding not to, or maybe later adding additional supplementary topics for a handful of students to pursue.

@DaveLRenfro, re, I would check the compatibility of such a variance with university guidelines.

Take a look at the whole Analytic Combinatorics (Flajolet and Sedgewick) stuff. Seemingly impossible combinatorial tasks made trivial by generating functions. Often cleanly sidestepping the "set up a recurrence relation" part.
The cited book is somewhat heavy going, perhaps look for easier texts, or distil the relevant parts for class use. Sedgewick and Flajolet's Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms (sorry, no PDF for this one) uses much of the machinery above for combinatoric's primary use nowaday.
